# HTML5 doctype causes SPAN tag with a special gap between top and bottom

Tags: html, css

The following example with HTML 4.01 Transitional doctype declaration, the span won't get the special gap between top and bottom.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="background:red"><span>dark green</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
span {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;    
}
```

But if we change it to use the HTML5 declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the span will get the special gap.

Here is the whole example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgLpf/) (if you change the Fiddle Options's DTD to use HTML5, you will see the problem there.

Comment: Hmm… even HTML 4.01 Strict does it, huh?

Comment: okay. what's the question?

Comment: If you give the `<div>` a `font-size` of `12px` instead of the `<span>`, that fixes it — but I have no idea why it behaves that way in Transitional.

Comment: The question is how to remove the gap of the span when using HTML5 doctype

Comment: @minitech: the answer is always "quirks mode". :(

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with how "line-height" is being calculated on the div element. Setting the "line-height" of the div element to the same "font-size" as the span is a way to fix this issue. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NgLpf/23/):

```
div { line-height: 12px; }
```

The Strict (and HTML5) DOCTYPEs [seem to enforce](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) "line-height" as if it was "min-height". Even if there isn't any text within the element, "line-height" is still applied.

The Transitional DOCTYPE triggers "Almost Standards" mode in browsers, which is basically [standards mode with a few quirks](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#almoststandardsmode).

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405794%28v=vs.85%29) explains the behavior of line height calculations in "Almost Standards" mode:

> Inline elements contribute to line height if and only if one of the following is true.
>
> If the element:
>
> - Contains text characters
> - Has a nonzero border width
> - Has a nonzero margin
> - Has a nonzero padding
> - Has a background image
> - Has vertical-align set to a value other than baseline
>
> Note that a line break is not considered a text character for this definition unless it is the only content of a line box. In that case, the line box height remains the uppermost inline box top and the lowermost inline box bottom on the line, regardless of the specified line height.
>
> If an **img** element is the sole content of a table cell, the line box height of the cell line box height is adjusted to zero.

Comment: Hi, even if I specify the line-height, the gap of the span is still there when using HTML5 doctype.

Comment: specify the line height on the div, not the span.

Comment: "The Strict (and HTML5) DOCTYPEs seem to enforce 'line-height' as if it was 'min-height'. Even if there isn't any text within the element, 'line-height' is still applied." This is a bit confusing; if there isn't any text or any content whatsoever within an element, then the element will have zero height. So `line-height` doesn't act like `min-height` in that sense.